# Bumpy node set up for metallic noisy texture

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I'm trying to emulate the texture of the metal-steel taps, which seem to have a fair bit of noise.
I was following a tutorial and the instructor added a Noise texture in the displacement, But I know from various tutorials I'm following regarding nodes, that you have to plug in the right colour nodes. So is this Node set up correct? Or how can I have a better result?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close. Generally if you're adding displacement information from a B&W texture, run it through the height input of a Displacement Node first before connecting it. You can go one further by plugging the texture into the height of a bump node as well, to take advantage of some of the normal information. However, by default, the strength of the Bump Node (1.0) is too high for many things. I reduced it, as well as the scale of the displacement - otherwise it's too "noisy" especially with the values you are using for the noise textures. See below:

[image: Hookup]

Comment: great, thanks for the Node screenshot!